# logging SCP activity in remote server

Tags: linux, scp, winscp

I have a CentOS server which is used by many person with same user.

All users are permitted to upload and download files with scp or winscp.
Is it possible to log all file transfer activity(in and out) with client IP in server?

I have apply the solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1257431/how-to-get-scp-logs-on-remote-server), but not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working from the solution you applied? Do you get an error? If so, which one?

Comment: #/bin/bash

scp-org $@ | tee >(grep -aEo "[CD][0-7]{4} [0-9]* .*$" --line-buffered >> /var/log/scp.log)

Comment: I cannot look through your eyes. You've now simply copy/pasted the command that is suggested, but you don't let us know what is not working for your. Please [edit] your question and include the command you've tried and the output you get.

Comment: Recently OpenSSH made `scp` use SFTP by default (2022-04-08, see the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0)). If a clients uses `scp` (or whatever) that uses SFTP then this statement "it actually also calles the binary on the Server with the `-f` flag" does not apply at all and any wrapper over `scp` on the server is irrelevant.

Comment: I have used `Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -l VERBOSE` , but i got no log.

Comment: Did you restart (or SIGHUP) the service after altering the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I have did so.